# Trying to centre a popupbox for any screen resolution

Tags: php, joomla2.5

How can I make a popup box appear at center of the screen for any screen resolution? The popupbox is displayed using the joomla popupbox plugin (content simple popup). Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a link to the site where you are implementing this?Also you can use this if its popup window.

```
function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) {
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
        var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. url :http://guntavnuk.pixabytes.co.in I need your help..
what  I have done is
in an article i have used the simple pop up plugin like this:
{simplepopup url="http://guntavnuk.pixabytes.co.in/guntavnuk/popup.php"}{/simplepopup}
where in popup.php contains code to display a background image and a email subscription form.

Currently I am working on (1360*768) resolution but when check for other resolution its not looking good.what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have used jQuery to make any element as popup box,
you can visit my git hub repository for details [complete popup box with example](https://github.com/vikas4488/popUpBox/blob/master/popupbox.html)
or alternatively,you can use my ripo as cdn too just copy this [raw git and paste in ur script tag](https://raw.githack.com/vikas4488/popUpBox/master/popupbox.js)